# Mock a single method of unit under test in Groovy

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, mocking

I have a simple class like

```
class SomeClass {
  def foo() {
    def bar= bar()
    switch( bar ) {
      return something based on format
    }
  }

  def bar() {
    return someValue
  }
}
```

I've already written complete unit tests for the `bar()`. Now I need to write unit tests for `foo()` which is heavily dependant on the use of `bar()` method. I don't want to duplicate the setup phase as done for `bar()`, so I'd like to mock it by simply returning values I want.

I'm aware that Groovy supports this sort of "mocking" easily by simply defining it like `SomeClass.property = "Hello World"`. Also, this can be done with collaborators as `SomeClass.service = myMockedService`. But I've not found a way to accomplish this with methods inside the unit under tests. Is there?

I tried with `MockFor` as in

```
def uut = new MockFor( SomeClass )
uut.demand.bar{ /* some values */ }
uut.use {
  assert uut.foo() == expected
}
```

but it gives me

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.mock.interceptor.MockFor.foo() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

**UPDATE**

In fact, I came up with a simple solution of using sub-classing. In the test method I create a subclass of `SomeClass` where I override the method I wish to mock/stub. After this, using an instance of the subclass gives me what I need.

This seems a bit rough, though. Any other suggestions on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to mock the value returned by `bar()` for a single instance of `SomeClass` you can use metaprogramming. Try the following in the Groovy console:

```
class SomeClass {
  def foo() {
  }

  def bar() {
    return 'real value'
  }
}

def uut = new SomeClass()

uut.metaClass.bar = {
  return 'mock value'
}

assert 'mock value' == uut.bar()
```

If you want to mock `bar()` for all instances of `SomeClass`, replace this:

```
uut.metaClass.bar = {
  return 'mock value'
}
```

with:

```
SomeClass.metaClass.bar = {
  return 'mock value'
}
```

Comment: Exactly the kind of solution I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dónal. I'm interested in your feedback on this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31129003/mock-gradle-project-exec-using-metaprogramming